# how to minimize td height when that td has text?

Tags: html, css

What I need is a 14px text, inside a 16px td (height).
When I try to do it with an empty td, this works, but when I put some text, the td takes a height of 20px automatically. That leaves a 2px top and bottom margin that I dont want.

**html:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>09:00 - 12:00</td><td>09:00 - 12:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>09:00 - 12:00</td><td>09:00 - 12:00</td></tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    background-color: #5589DC;
    color:white;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 16px;
}
```

This is the result (20px td height):

[image]

But this is what I want (16px td height (modified with paint)):

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Sure, I've solved it with @Juanín help: https://jsfiddle.net/wp15845b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change height:16px to line-height:13px, that will reduce the space within the TD.

Answer (score 2):

You need only to set the `line-height` to match the `font-size`, i.e. `line-height: 14px`.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    background-color: #5589DC;
    color: white;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text on a div and give the div a height of 16px